# bevel doesn't work right

Tags: bevel

Im using last version of blender and when I want to bevel, blender does this:

[image]

instead of this: (make it manually)

[image]

so maybe this happens because I have my configurations wrong but I don't know how to turn it as default (if thats the reason)

Someone knows how to make the bevel work normal?

WITHOUT MODIFIER! JUST WITH THE BEVEL TOOL IN EDIT MODE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you press n and go to:
item -> transform -> scale
can you see if the scale is all 1?

for example scale is all 1

[image]

if it is not all 1, for example, if it is something like (4, 1, 0), it is not all 1

[image]

if this is the case, this might help: go into object mode, select the object that is causing the error, Press ctrl+A, and then choose Scale

[image]

now check to see if the scale is now is all 1. If it is try beveling again.

I hope this helps

if it does not work. Do you happen to have other modifiers or connections to other objects that might be changing the scale of the object?

Comment: with all 1, the bevel works but i lose the structure of the object, I mean that if I can make a bevel which doesn't care about the scale of the object, because if I make the bevel in with all 1 and scale it back to the structure I want, the bevel also its scaled

Comment: If the object scale was not all 1, setting the scale to all 1 manually should cause the object to deform. However, if you select the object and press ctrl+a you can apply the scaling. this will set the scaling to all 1 and retain the structure of the object.

Comment: ok my fault, Thanks!!